# Chrome will close the tcp connection if content-length is wrong?

Tags: http, go, tcp

I am interested in the action of web server to http keep-alive header. So I built a simple http server based on http server. The server does nothing but response to the client with a simple html http body.

The code of server is here:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:9765")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error listening:", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer l.Close()
    for {
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        fmt.Println("New connection...")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error accepting: ", err.Error())
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        go handleRequest(conn)
    }
}

// handler
func handleRequest(conn net.Conn) {
    for {
        buf := make([]byte, 512)
        _, err := conn.Read(buf)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error reading:", err.Error())
            conn.Close()
            break
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s", buf)
        str := `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 8
Content-Type: application/javascript

alert(1)

`
        conn.Write([]byte(str))
    }
}
```

I added a demo html to local nginx static server:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type=text/javascript src="test.js"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="http://localhost:9765/3"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="http://localhost:9765/2"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="http://localhost:9765/1"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="http://localhost:9765/17"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="http://localhost:9765/16"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="http://localhost:9765/15"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="http://localhost:9765/14"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="http://localhost:9765/13"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="http://localhost:9765/12"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="http://localhost:9765/30"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="http://localhost:9765/29"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="http://localhost:9765/28"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="http://localhost:9765/27"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="http://localhost:9765/26"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="http://localhost:9765/25"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="http://localhost:9765/24"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="http://localhost:9765/23"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="http://localhost:9765/22></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="http://localhost:9765/21"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>loader测试页面</h1>
<span>hello world</span>
</body>

</html>
```

When visit the file with chrome, I found all response is normal, but tcp connection was closed after every single http request. The TCP got EOF error after sending http response.

Comment: It is not fully clear what you are asking: your code is in golang but you are asking about some behavior of nginx. Apart from that your code explicitly only sends a single request per TCP connection (which likely even has the content-length wrong: 7 bytes text and 2 newlines is not 8) so the behavior you see is expected. I have the feeling that you currently don't really understand the mapping between accept and TCP connection and what exactly the server is supposed to do with HTTP keep-alive (keep the connection open for the next request).

Comment: All I want to find out is why the TCP connection is closed after every http request, even though I add keep-alive header to the http response. After fix the content-length, tcp connection are reused by following http requests. I guess the chrome may close the tcp connection if the http response check failed.

Comment: @shanyy That's not so surprising. If you tell the browser your reply contains an 8 byte body, but you actually send it a few more bytes say 2 more bytes the browser will not know what to do with those 2 characters and consider it a violation of the HTTP protocol. The most sensible thing to do in such a case is to just close the connection.

Comment: Another issue is that the header line terminators are missing the `\r`, but Chrome probably handles that.

Comment: @shanyy: the HTTP keep-alive header is just telling the browser that the server would be willing to keep the connection open. Only, your server closes the connection since all was your code does is accept, read, write and finish - the last thing closes the connection. For proper keep alive you would need to accept the connection, read request, write response, read next request ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you send the wrong content length in the header, the browser will either hang (waiting for content that will never come) or close the connection (when it sees invalid junk after the content). What else could it do?